# Resolution Problems

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, resolution

Hope I'm in the right place! So I'm trying to play Diablo 3, but my main computer recently broke down and I can't fix it yet. I have a backup computer that only has Intel HD embedded graphics. I can only play the game at or less than a resolution of 1024x768 or it lags terribly and becomes unplayable. The problem is that when I select those resolutions on my 1080p monitor it looks terrible. Is there something I can do about this? Also my copy of windows 8 isnt letting me go below 1024x768 - is there a way of getting a lower resolution when it is not available by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop and go to screen resolution.

Then go to the advanced settings, in the adapter tab click on the button that says list all modes.

These are all the modes your GPU supports. (But not necessarily your monitor.) You are going to have to tinker with it till you get the display mode that works ok for your monitor and the game you are trying to play.

Comment: I AM using windows 8 - how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1024 x 768 resolution does not match the 16:9 aspect ratio of a 1080p monitor, which is one reason why it looks horrible.

In the Intel display settings, try setting the "scaling" feature to either "maintain aspect ratio" or "center image."

"Maintain aspect" will keep the game's 1024x768 4:3 aspect and it should scale the height, leaving black bars on the left and right margins of the monitor.

"Center image" will mean the game's viewport will not be scaled to the height of the monitor so you will have black bars vertically and horizontally. However, this *might* give a slight performance boost as the display is not being scaled up by the GPU.